# how to set variable name for google cloud instance

Tags: linux, shell, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sdk

PROB_INSTANCE_NAME=INSTANCE_NAME

not working

> C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud
> SDK>PROB_INSTANCE_NAME=lamp-1-vm 'PROB_INSTANCE_NAME' is not
> recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
> batch file.
>
> C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>set PROB_INSTANCE_NAME=lamp-1-vm
>
> C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud compute instances
> stop "$PROB_INSTANCE_NAME" ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.stop)
> HTTPError 400: Invalid value '$PROB_INSTANCE_NAME'. Values must match
> the following regular expression: 'a-z?'

i am using google gcloud tool on the desktop.

trying to install Linux guest environment by cloning root disk.

Comment: According to the message "Values must match the following regular expression: 'a-z?'" seems like $PROB_INSTANCE_NAME can only contain lowercase letters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are using Linux or Windows, Looking your commands looks like you are using Windows. If you are using Windows the correct commands are:

1) look if you are using the correct user and project

```
gcloud status
```

2) in case that you aren't using the correct user account or project you can config these settings by executing.

```
gcloud init
```

3) set your instance as a variable

```
set PROB_INSTANCE_NAME=lamp-1-vm
```

4) exec the stop command by using the variable and the zone

```
gcloud compute instances stop %PROB_INSTANCE_NAME% --zone zone_of_your_instance
```